# Are recursive Horn clauses first order?

Tags: logic, recursion, prolog

My understanding is that recursive definitions are considered second-order since they require the fixpoint operator in order to be formulated as "true" definitions. This is even though they contain no higher order quantifiers eg.

```
times(x,s(y)) = plus(x,times(x,y))
times(x,0) = 0
```

needs to be written as `times = \mu x. F(x)` for some F, and the fixpoint operator is second order. I believe the same is true for recursive Horn clauses. But then why is a Prolog program considered first order, since it typically contains many recursive rules?

Answer (score 4):

Horn clauses in prolog are *not* recursive definitions. They are *logical formulas*. For example,

```
times(_, 0, 0).
times(x, S(y), w) :- times(x,y,z), plus(x,z,w).
```

is *not* the definition of a recursive function, but just two logical formulas, written fully as
\begin{gather*}
\forall x .\, \mathtt{times}(x, 0, 0), \\
\forall x, y, w, z .\, \mathtt{times}(x,y,z) \land \mathtt{plus}(x,z,w) \Rightarrow \mathtt{times}(x,S(y),w).
\end{gather*}
Here $\mathtt{times}$ and $\mathtt{plus}$ are ternary relation symbols, $0$ is a constant, and $\mathtt{S}$ is a unary function symbol.

It is the case that the above formulas tell prolog how to search for solution to queries using a strategy (depth-first search) that resembles computation of functions given by recursive definitions, but the formulas themselves are just first-order logic statement.

As for the necessity of using the fixpoint $\mu$ operator for recursive definitions, there is no such necessity. We can directly define first-order functions using a schema that allows self reference. Such a schema *may* be translated to an application of $\mu$, but it does not have to be. One can explain it directly. For instance, [primitive recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) are defined such a schema, without any fixed point operator.